# VS Code editor | How to include -x switch for ShellCheck?

Tags: scripting, shellcheck, visual-studio-code

#### Problem description and reproduction

In terminal run:

```
shellcheck -x my_script
```

Where `my_script` sources another (partial) script.

I get no error with the `-x` switch, but if I run it **without `-x`**:

```
shellcheck my_script
```

I get notification like this one:

```
. ./functions/my_function

  ^-- SC1091: Not following: ... was not specified as input (see shellcheck -x).
```

[SC1091 on GitHub](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1091)

---

#### My ShellCheck

I'm working with self-compiled ShellCheck located in:

```
~/.cabal/bin/shellcheck
```

---

#### Goal

I'm working with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) GUI text editor. Is there a way to force the `-x` switch in there somewhere or other solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside VS Code, the ShellCheck extension can be [configured](https://github.com/timonwong/vscode-shellcheck/blob/master/README.md#options) with optional arguments; from the settings, either in its GUI directly or by editing `settings.json`.

[image: ShellCheck Custom Args setting in GUI directly]

[image: ShellCheck Custom Args setting.json file]

So, you may open `settings.json`, and add something like:

```
"shellcheck.customArgs": ["-x"],
```

(Thanks to [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) for the hint.)

There are a couple of ways to use `-x` regardless of the tool invoking `shellcheck`:

- you can [set default options](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/blob/master/shellcheck.1.md#environment-variables) in `SHELLCHECK_OPTS`:

  ```
    export SHELLCHECK_OPTS='-x'
  ```
- you could replace your binary:

  ```
    mv ~/.cabal/bin/shellcheck{,-real}
    printf '#!/bin/sh\nshellcheck-real -x "$@"\n' > ~/.cabal/bin/shellcheck
    chmod 755 ~/.cabal/bin/shellcheck
  ```